# Difference between times using date function MACOSX

Tags: macos

Calculate duration in HH:MM:SS format using difference in start and end time.

```
# Time Arithmetic
TIME1="00:30:20"
TIME2="00:30:50"

# Convert the times to seconds from the Epoch

SEC1=`date -j -f '%T' $TIME1 "+%s"`
#echo $SEC1
SEC2=`date -j -f '%T' $TIME2 "+%s"`
#echo $SEC2


# Use expr to do the math, let's say TIME1 was the start and TIME2 was the finish
DIFFSEC=`expr ${SEC2} - ${SEC1}`
#echo $DIFFSEC

echo Start ${TIME1}
echo Finish ${TIME2}

echo Took ${DIFFSEC} seconds.

# And use date to convert the seconds back to something more meaningful
result=`date -r $DIFFSEC "+%T"`
echo Result ${result}
```

## Expected : Result <s>00:30:30</s> 00:00:30(corrected)

## Actual : Result 05:30:30

**EDIT** Actual TIME1 and TIME2 will be coming as params, and intension here is not to calculate time elapsed. It is a sample code i have used to demonstrate the issue. Strangely when TIME1=05:30:20 and TIME2=05:30:50 then also Result is : 05:30:30 
Corrected Subject.

Comment: You can do timing in the shell just using bash's built-in variable `$SECONDS`, try `echo $SECONDS; sleep 3; echo $SECONDS`, or `start=$SECONDS; sleep 3; echo $((SECONDS-start))`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Actual intent is not to calculate time elapsed, but the duration using two time inputs with format HH:MM:SS

Comment: In effect, you are asking `date` in the penultimate line to tell you what the time is now it is 30 seconds after the epoch, i.e. just after midnight 1 Jan 1970.

Comment: yes , I am trying something similar to [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/time-difference-calculation-4175459414/). Also, I have updated expected output accordingly, sorry for confusion.

Comment: I am not interested in Date part as such, if there is an alternative to calculate time difference without epoch, I am happy to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally settled with below, thanks anyways.

```
result=$(printf '%02d:%02d:%02d' $(($DIFFSEC/3600)) $(($DIFFSEC%3600/60)) $(($DIFFSEC%60)))
```